# Commit multiple rows to the database on a single button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form page that should update multiple rows in a database table. I have used ViewModel to generate the Form page UI.

I want each row in the UI table to be send as a row to the database table.

[image: Screenshot of UI]

[image: Screenshot of the Table]

The OptionValueID is set in the controller. But the value for the TcSetID comes from the ID of the Property in the UI.

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {

         var model = new SetValue { OptionValueID = id };
        var ov = db.OptionValue.Include(x => x.Option).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionValueID == id);
        var opid = ov.OptionID;
        var op = db.Option.Include(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristic).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionID == opid);
        var tcid = op.TechnicalCharacteristicID;
        var tc = db.TechnicalCharacteristic.Include(x => x.TcSets).FirstOrDefault(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristicID == tcid);
        var tcset = tc.TcSets;
        var opv = db.OptionValue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionValueID == id);
        ViewBag.OptionValue = opv.OptionVal;
        ViewBag.Option = opv.Option.OptionName;
        ViewBag.Lsystem = opv.Option.Lsystem.LsystemName;
        ViewBag.FamilyName = opv.Option.Lsystem.LsystemFamily.FamilyName;
        ViewBag.TcSetID = new SelectList(tcset, "TcSetID", "SetName");
        //ViewBag.OptionValueID = new SelectList(db.OptionValue,"OptionValueID","OptionVal",)
        return View(model);
    }

public class SetValue
{
    public int SetValueID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }


    public int TcSetID { get; set; }
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }

    public virtual OptionValue OptionValue { get; set; }
    public virtual TcSet TcSet { get; set; }

}
```

View (Excerpt where ViewModel is being used)

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OptionValueID)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TcSetID, "TcSetID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("TcSetID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TcSetID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to submit all the values to the Create method that saves the value to the table. The data in the database table in the image was added manually.

I have tried to create a list of objects of the ViewModel. As I have read in a few questions in SO. But I am unable to create a list of ViewModel objects because it shows ViewModel is a type and is being used as a variable.

```
List<AddSetValue> as = new List<AddSetValue> {new AddSetValue{SetValue=new SetValue{OptionValueID=6},TcSet=tcset.TcSets}};
```

As i have read in other answers I should index each row in my View and has to commit it each row in a forloop in my Post Create method. But I am unable to assign a list at the moment.

Are there any other ways to commit multiple rows to the database?

Comment: the are really no one who knows a work around for this? I am still unable to find a work around. looking forward to someone's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list for viewModel, just create a List of the object. Something in the way of (But add your properties correctly, because I'm not fully understanding your object.

```
var viewModel = new List<AddSetValue>();

viewModel.Add(new AddSetValue
{
    SetValue = new SetValue{
        OptionValueID = 6
    }
};
```

In the view you should have following model add the top:

```
@model List<ViewModels.AddSetValue>
```

Instead of :

```
@model ViewModels.AddSetValue
```

After those changes, you should be able to iterate over your list of objects... You should go with the index list option:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have assignes the value of the Foreign Key because I wanted to check the functionality of the Method separately. And I have tried adding `List<ViewModels.AddSetValue>` But it did not work. I will edit my question with what I currently having. Now the UI also doesnt accept multiple values. i am trying to render a partial View so that I can work the create button in my Index page.

Comment: You're view should work with a list! Almost every index page is build with a list in my projects.

Comment: Yes. My View should work with a list. My list contains another list in it. Maybe that could be the reason I cant get it right.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I already tried the indexing. There are no errors, but the Submit doesnt work

Comment: I have changed the Post create method to accept a list and in a for loop i did an individual commit to the database. But the function itself wasn't called.

Comment: Your post should accept a list, but in the page, you should have a form, where inside you loop over the objects. Then out of the loop, you should have a submit button, that submits the entire list of objects.

Comment: AFAIK i have done it that way. i found that on some other question in SO. I can post the code with the loops. Give me some time. Because I have to write it all over again.